# Location of 'client_iden' parameter for Pushbullet client

Tags: pushbullet

I'm trying to use the 'client_iden' target parameter to send pushes to multiple users at once. I've successfully created the client, but I'm unable to find the 'client_iden' parameter on the client creation page.

Does anyone know where this parameter can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that!  I think that used to be there but we must have accidentally removed it.  You should create a Push object with an access token for your Client.  Then check the client_iden on that Push.  Unfortunately that's probably the easiest way to find this information right now.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/devices
Username = your API key, password = blank
You can find all your device_idens in the returned json